# How to query all tables in a database

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatable

I'm writing MySQL to get all unique IDs from all tables in a database.

The database has tables like record_20181201, record_20181202, ...

The tables are automatically generated based on date (all tables have the same schema, and one column name is visitorId).

The SQL query I made is like,

```
SELECT UNIQUE(visitorId) FROM databaseName.record_20181201;
```

I can only query one table at a time using this..

Is there a way to query all tables in the database and select all unique visitorIds there?

Comment: @RiggsFolly Thanks for the answer. Can you elaborate a little more (maybe sample code)? I'm new to SQL.

Comment: A different table for each date?

Comment: Side comment: It sounds like potentially bad database design to have multiple tables all with an identical schema.  Any chance you could consolidate the tables into a single table, with a date column to distinguish?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Potentially ????? :)

Comment: @RiggsFolly Maybe if the OP is taking in massive amounts per data, it might be _logically_ justified.  But, even in that case, it would still be better to have a single logical table with some sort of partition.

Comment: Hey @TimBiegeleisen I am agreeing with you whole heatedly

Comment: It would be better a more specific title stating which database are you talking about, because this is the kind of thing that changes depending on the RDBMS vendor and version.

Comment: @Rafael There is a tag for **MYSQL** which shoudl give you a clue

Comment: I had to solve a problem like this, in Oracle, about 20 years ago.  My solution, even if I could remember it, would have to be massively changed to fit your situation.  How many tables are we talking about here?  A few dozen?  Hundreds? Are you able to use tools outside of SQL to generate a query that combines all these tables using UNION, as suggested in one of the answers?

Comment: Given that the OP is new to SQL, it seems like a stretch to suggest a redesign of the database, although a redesign is much needed.  Perhaps a view with the mother of all UNIONS in it would be more achievable.

Comment: @RiggsFolly why did you delete your answer?  It's a part of the solution.  I don't know MYSQL myself, or I would come up with a way to get the same result by querying the dictionary  (aka system tables).  Taking the answer and storing it in a variable like $result sounds like scripting more than SQL.  Is that your reason for deleting your answer?

Comment: @WalterMitty I came to the conclusion that as there was no **PHP** tag the OP probably was not interested in a programatic solution and that they were probably using a `phpMyAdmin` or similiar tool to do whatever they are doing.

Comment: @RigsFoly, the point of my sugestion (not critic) still stands. (1) people read the title first, (2) "a database" is misleading because it implies there is a generic solution for the problem regardless of what engine is used, (3) the title would be even shorter if she wrote "How to query all tables in MySQL" (4) putting MySQL in the title would draw much more attention from a MySQL specialist rather than an Oracle specialist like me.

Comment: @Rafael Mostly, people tend to filter the new questions list on TAGS, but I am not actually disagreeing with you presay

Comment: @RiggsFolly yeah, I'm with you.  If had to solve this problem myself, I would use a table driven template expander that I wrote in powershell.  I would use a query on the INFORMATION_SCHEMA to get the names of the tables into a CSV file, use my tool to generate the mother of all UNIONS, do a little fixing with a text editor, and run the resulting SQL query to get the results.  But I'm not about to suggest this to the OP, an SQL newbie.

Comment: @WalterMitty You sound like a sensible chap. :) Always tailor the solution to the percieved experience of the OP

Comment: Yeah.  In addition to being a DBA, I taught a few little courses on database programming or database design and development.  Teaching makes you realize that the ignorant people are not stupid.

Comment: ...and I really don't know if the OP built this database, while still new at SQL  (shudder) or inherited a legacy system that was badly built (shudder).

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT VisitorID FROM DBName.Table1
 UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT VisitorID FROM DBName.Table2 
 UNION 
SELECT DISTINCT VisitorID FROM DBName.Table3
```

Try this!!!!!!Hope this helps..

Comment: A more perfect answer would be one where the op doesn't have to add a union statement every day,.

Comment: Please remember, perfect is in the eye of the beholder, only :)

Comment: Or at least where the addition of a new union statement could be automated.  That is how I dealt with a similar problem 20 years ago.  However, the automation was done in a scripting language, and NOT in SQL.  It is possible to write script generating queries in SQL,  but the technique is **far** from elementary.  Remember, the OP is new to SQL.

Comment: I'll have to agree with P.Salmon. The database has hundreds of tables, and new tables are generated everyday... I really don't want to manually UNION them all.

Answer (score 0):

You could generate a query string with UNION's from the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.

Then run that query, or put it in a view.

A `UNION` will return a unique combined result of the unioned queries.
While a `UNION ALL` would just stick the results together.

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(Qry ORDER BY TblSchema, TblName SEPARATOR ' UNION ')
FROM
(
  SELECT 
   TABLE_SCHEMA as TblSchema,
   TABLE_NAME as TblName,
   CONCAT('select visitorId from ',TABLE_SCHEMA,'.',TABLE_NAME,'\r\n') as Qry
  FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
  WHERE TABLE_NAME LIKE 'record_201812%' 
    AND COLUMN_NAME = 'visitorId'
) Q;
```

Comment: I think it should be where TABLE_NAME LIKE 'record_%'

Comment: There should be the word UNION in front ot the word SELECT for all entries except the first one.

Comment: @WalterMitty That depends if Emma wants to select from all those record tables, or just a specific month.  And the group_concat will only put the ' union ' between the queries.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't catch the GROUP_CONCAT.

Answer (score 0):

Run below query you will get a single query that will give unique visitorId from all table.

```
SELECT 
    CONCAT('SELECT DISTINCT visitorId FROM (',
            REPLACE(query_string, ',', ' UNION '),
            ') union_table') AS final_query
FROM
    (SELECT 
        CONCAT(GROUP_CONCAT('SELECT visitorId FROM ', table_name)) AS query_string
    FROM
        information_schema.tables
    WHERE
        table_name LIKE 'record_%') table_a;
```

you will get below query that will fetch unique visitorId from all tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    visitorId
FROM
    (
    SELECT visitorId FROM record_20181201 
        UNION 
    SELECT visitorId FROM record_20181202 
        UNION 
    SELECT visitorId FROM record_20181203
    ) union_table
```